# Heat equation with sin initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

How do i find the analytical solution of the heat equation:

$$U_t = U_{xx} + \sin{\pi x}$$ 
subject to $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$ and $u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x).$

I appreciate its a pretty common/general question but i have searched and cannot find any articles explaining this very well. So either an explanation or a link to a good explanation will be appreciated

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. We appreciate see your efforts about the subject.

Comment: Solve the homogeneous part $u_{t} = u_{xx}$, then substitute that solution into your PDE and solve for the whole solution. Google "inhomogeneous heat equation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the steady-state solution of the inhomogeneous equation with your boundary conditions is $u_p(x) = \sin(\pi x)/\pi^2$.

If $u_h(x,t)$ solves the homogeneous equation with your boundary conditions
and initial condition $u(x,0) = (what?)$, then 
$u(x,t) = u_p(x) + u_h(x,t)$ is your desired solution.

Fortunately the homogeneous equation has some nice solutions of the form
$ u_h(x,t) = \sin(\pi x) T(t)$ (what is $T(t)$?).

Comment: Thanks for the help @RobertIsrael, I solved the homogeneous equation with my boundary conditions to be:

uh(x,t) = exp(-tπ^2)Sin(πx)?

So thus 

u(x,t) = exp(-tπ^2)Sin(πx) + sin(πx)/π^2? 

I read before that you should set u(x,0) equal to your steady state solution so i have doubts about this answer as i didn't change u(x,0)

Comment: If you want $u(x,0) = u_p(x) + u_h(x,0) = \sin(\pi x)$, then you'll need  $u_h(x,0) = \sin(\pi x) - u_p(x)$.  What you have is close, but not quite right.

Comment: Okay i've changed it to u(x,t) = Sin(πx)/π^2 + exp(-tπ^2)(1-1/π^2)Sin(πx) which i'm pretty sure is now correct after subbing it back in and validating initial conditions.

Many thanks for your help